# Elasticsearch match_bool_prefix query fails with ampersand at the end of the query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've come upon a weird issue with match_bool_prefix (with one term) query working differently than the prefix query. From what I understand match_bool_prefix should analyze my query and then create a multi-term query with each term and the last should be a prefix query. In my case, my query is part of an email address and ends with an @. Here's my example:

**Create Index**

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/testindex' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "settings":{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "default": {
                "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
                "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
        }
    }
  },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "email":{
                "type":"text"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

**Add data**

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/_doc/1' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email":"tester@gmail.com"
}'
```

**Failing Query**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "query": {
        "match_bool_prefix": {
            "email": "tester@"
        }
    }
}'
```

**Working Query**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "email": {
                "value": "tester@"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Querying with the word 'tester' works with both queries which shows it is using a prefix. Also using another analyzer (keyword, or whitespace) on the match_bool_prefix query works correctly. Which makes me think Elasticsearch isn't doing the right thing. According to the docs, the match_bool_prefix should analyze the query into tokens which in my case would strip off the @ according to this analyze query:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/_analyze' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "explain": "false",
    "analyzer":"default",
    "text" : "tester@"
}
'

results

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "tester",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

So this is what the match_bool_prefix query should actually look like but this one works great:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [
        { "prefix": { "email": "tester"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm working on a much larger query but the results of this had me questioning if I was using the match_bool_prefix query correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `match_bool_prefix` query has been created specifically to be used with the [`search_as_you_type` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html) ([see #35600](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/35600)).

Since you're searching for email prefixes (or whole emails), you can simply use the `prefix` query since email addresses are never composed of several terms, especially since you're analyzing it with an `uax_url_email` tokenizer. So there's no point in using a `match_bool_prefix` query in this case.

Comment: I made my query into this a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. My query is part of a very large multifield query. I wouldn't say that **match_bool_prefix** was created for **search_as_you_type** but it fits very well with it (maybe you have inside information). Yes I agree that I can use a prefix for this simple case. However, what is the reason the initial query fails when it shouldn't.

Comment: If you check the ticket I've linked to, you'll see that the query was born at the same time as the search as you type field type, so yes, they go hand in hand. As to the reason it fails is because of the analyzer you have which tokenizes the text using [unicode text segmentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/), which is pretty specific.

Comment: The analyzer returns the word I expect, however, the functionality is not working as expected. Either the docs are wrong or its a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> match_bool_prefix should analyze my query and then create a multi-term query with each term and the last should be a prefix query

Yes, the `match_bool_prefix` analyse the query **BUT** it uses the analyzer from the queried field’s mapping. keep in mind that the `uax_url_email` tokenizer does NOT split emails & URLs, thus there will be no matches for your query.

I suggest either changing the field mapping to `keyword` :

```
PUT stackindex_002
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
                "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
        }
    }
  },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "email":{
                "type":"keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or adding an explicit analyzer in the query :

```
GET testindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_bool_prefix": {
          "email": {
            "query": "tester@",
            "analyzer": "keyword"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The problem with that is my query is ‘tester@‘ and the value in the index is ‘tester@gmail.com’. My query ‘tester@‘ analyzes to one term ‘tester’. And ‘tester’ is a prefix of ‘tester@gmail.com’. Why isn’t the prefix found using the match_bool_prefix which should be equivalent to the prefix query since there’s only one term. I know how to work around the problem but why is it an issue? Looks the documentation and example and you’ll see what I mean: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query.html